# How do I get past an accept dialog using scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I need to scrape a site that has an accept dialog that I need to get through first. The form is as follows:

<form action="/lst_sale/" method="post"> <input class="button" type="submit" value="Accept"/> </form>

Clicking the accept button takes me to the page with a table that I need to parse. Right now I have:

```
# function to parse markup
def parse(self, response):        
    yield FormRequest(url="http://www.somedomain.com/lst_sale",
                      method="POST",
                      formdata={},
                      callback=self.parse_list)


def parse_list(self, response):
    # do something...
```

Problem is parse_list never gets called so I am assuming that the form post is not happening. Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Thx!

Comment: I understand now that it's a cookie issue. I have tried using yield FormRequest.from_response(response, clickdata={ "value" : "Accept"}, callback=self.parse_list) but that doesnt' work either. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. Turns out I was not sending the proper values. Now works using:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield FormRequest.from_response(
                    response, 
                    formdata={"value":"Accept"}, 
                    callback=self.after_accept)

def after_accept(self, response):
    yield Request("http://example.com?some_vars=some_values", callback=self.parse_list)

def parse_list(self, response):
    #begin scraping!
```

This handles the ASP.NET_SessionId for me. I set COOKIES_DEBUG = True in settings.py and that showed me that the sessions were indeed being handled - which led me to finding the root of my issue. I hope.